# Returning list in axis2 web service

Tags: web-services, soap, apache-axis

Hi I want to return a list from web service. My code is

```
public class WebListTest {
    public List serviceFunction(String arg1,String arg2)
    {
    List list=new ArrayList();
        list.add(arg1);
        list.add(arg2);
            return list;    

        }
}
```

But in wsdl creation i found

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
```

and when in invoking this webservice from a client i get the exception

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Any type element type has not been given
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at webservice1.WebListTestStub.fromOM(WebListTestStub.java:1622)
    at webservice1.WebListTestStub.serviceFunction(WebListTestStub.java:191)
    at webservice1.ServiceTest.main(ServiceTest.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Any type element type has not been given
    at webservice1.WebListTestStub$ServiceFunctionResponse$Factory.parse(WebListTestStub.java:917)
    at webservice1.WebListTestStub.fromOM(WebListTestStub.java:1616)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Any type element type has not been given
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.getAnyTypeObject(ConverterUtil.java:1612)
    at webservice1.WebListTestStub$ServiceFunctionResponse$Factory.parse(WebListTestStub.java:895)
    ... 3 more
```

now what I do.please help.

Answer (score 7):

You should not use Java Collection types when returning data from Axis2 POJO Web Service Objects, you should return arrays of objects or primitive types instead. WSDL doesn't allow Java Collection data structures. Remember that a web service needs to be accessable from any language and they do not use same collection framework as Java nessassarily.

So, do something like this:

```
public class WebListTest {
    public String[] serviceFunction(String arg1,String arg2) {

    List<String> stringList=new ArrayList<String>();

    stringList.add(arg1);
    stringList.add(arg2);

    return stringList.toArray( new String[stringList.size()] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why though, worked for me. Maybe changes in different versions?

Comment: Nope its not because Arraylist cannot cast into the String array. bcoz actually u can not use collection classes because its not supported by the SOAP services. we have to use array or String data type

Comment: But the code I provided does not return any collection class based objects, it returns an array.

Comment: But you are trying to Cast List means collection class in to array that wont possible na.. Because you can not cast List into Array there is Class Can not be Cast exception...

Comment: Tell me One thing that have you tried your code.?? to Cast that into Array.

Comment: Ya now it may be correct. but i will accept it after once i check it.. :)

Comment: I took it from a solution here on StackExchange. :)

Comment: Ya its resolving error of Class cast exception but still m getting Instantiation Exception in my client page. dont know why...

Answer (score 0):

You can change return type from "List" to "List< String >"  ,and it will work fine.

```
public class WebListTest {
    public List<String> serviceFunction(String arg1,String arg2)
    {
        List<String> list=new ArrayList();
        list.add(arg1);
        list.add(arg2);
        return list;    

    }
}
```